# Import duration from xlsx / convert object to duration

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am using Python to webscrape lots of xlsx files (all in the same format) and consolidate them into a single file ready for further analysis using

```
In [206]:    
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
df= pd.DataFrame()
df =  pd.concat([pd.read_excel(fp, index_col = 0, header = 3).assign(New=os.path.basename(fp)) for fp in files])
df.dtypes

Out[206]: 
HVR\n>60                                int64
AVG HVR                                 object
Longest HVR                             datetime64[ns]
```

AVG HVR and Longest HVR are both durations but some fields in AVG HVR contain millisenconds hence the data type in object like so:

```
Site           AVG HVR
Leighton       1900-01-01 00:18:30.080000
Macclesfield   1900-01-01 00:23:09
```

I need to process these on as durations in excel so need to either convert them to a timedelta format or import them from xlsx in the correct format.

I have tried all the below to no avail,

```
df['AVG HVG'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['AVG HVG'])
>>> TypeError: Expected unicode, got Timestamp
>>> ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
datetime.combine(date.min, df['AVG HVG']) - datetime.min
>>> TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not Series
df['AVG HVG'] = df['AVG HVG'] - datetime.time(1900, 1, 1)
>>> TypeError: descriptor 'time' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
df['AVG HVR'] = df['AVG HVR'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
>>> KeyError: 'AVG HVR'
df['AVG HVR\n(HH:MM:SS)'] = df['AVG HVR\n(HH:MM:SS)'].astype('|S19')
```

Answer (score 0):

***Background:*** Excel stores dates as a serial date, days since 1900 by default. See also: [Dates and Times in Excel](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm). But there's no dedicated type for duration in Excel, they are just dates in Excel as well. So upon import into the pandas dataframe, you'll get `datetime` instead of `timedelta`.

***Datetime to Timedelta:*** Instead of trying to cast to timedelta (which is not defined for datetime -> timedelta), simply subtract the reference date from the datetime column to get a timedelta column.

***Ex:***

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'AVG HVR': [pd.Timestamp("1900-01-01 00:18:30.080000"), 
                               pd.Timestamp("1900-01-01 00:23:09")]})

df['AVG HVR'] = df['AVG HVR'] - pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01')
```

```
df['AVG HVR']

0   0 days 00:18:30.080000
1          0 days 00:23:09
Name: AVG HVR, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however when I try this I get the following error: 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'Timestamp'

Comment: @voluzy hm what dtype is `df['AVG HVR']`? maybe try to call a `df['AVG HVR'] = pd.to_datetime(df['AVG HVR'])` first.

Comment: As far as I can tell the type is 'object', this is the error i get when I try your suggestion: TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: @voluzy That doesn't add up with your example - e.g. `1900-01-01 00:18:30.080000` cannot be datetime.time since it has a date

Comment: @voluzy you can also try `df['AVG HVR'] = pd.to_datetime(df['AVG HVR'].astype(str))`